# casperjs: how to trigger a jquery $.ajax call

Tags: jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a working casperjs script but it's only successfully executing the $.ajax call around 50% of the time.

I know it's working because I can see the new data show up in my api logs when it does work, and I can see the field updated in the database.  On the failed attempts I see no activity on my api, so it seems it's not even firing off the ajax call.  What would cause this ajax call to work only some of the time?  The casper log line always returns null even when it does update my db field.  Here is the code snippet.  I'm using GET since it's cross domain.

```
casper.then(function() {
    // Needs local copy of jquery right?
    this.page.injectJs('C:/jquery.min.js');

    response = this.evaluate(function() {

    var params = { "stuffIWantToSave" : "1000" };
    var foo = $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      data: params,
      url: 'http://api.mysite.com/update',
      success: function (data) {
        return data;
      },
      error: function (xhr,status,error){
        return error;
      }
    }); // end $.ajax call
  }); // end this.evaluate

  casper.log('Ajax response:', 'info');
  casper.log(JSON.stringify(foo), 'info');

  this.die('End');

});// end casper.then(function()
```

I'm new to casperjs so I'd appreciate pointing out any other errors in my code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that jQuery isn't getting injected into the page until after the `evaluate()` gets called.

To test if this is the case, you can put the following towards the top of your script and it will let you know if there are any errors being thrown on the remote page.

```js
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});
```

If this is the case, you can just move the inject into another `then()` block

```js
casper.then(function() {
    this.page.injectJs('C:/jquery.min.js');
});

casper.then(function() {
    response = this.evaluate(function() {
        . . .
    });
});
```

Or you could move the injection into `create()`, but then you would be injecting jQuery into every page load instead of just the one.

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["C:/jquery.min.js"]
});
```